# The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property - Selenium Error

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an infuriating Selenium error:

> The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property

Here is the code I am using:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.chrome.driver", @"C:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe");

DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
capability.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);

Uri url = new Uri("http://localhost:5050/wd/hub");

//error on this line
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capability);
```

I have the driver on disk, at the location.

The selenium server is running, as shown below:

[Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFRW0.png)

I have added the selenium binary as a system variable, as shown below:

[Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJSEC.png)

I have restarted the server too.

What am I missing? It feels as though I am doing everything correctly, but it's not working.

Thanks

Comment: Forget everything, just run server jar in cmd as : `java - jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver = "C:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe"`.. problem solved..:)

Answer (score 1):

With the new selenium, which is 3.0 you should use:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=path_to_chrome_driver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar
```

If you are using selenium version below 3.0 you need to reverse the order of selenium with the driver, like:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=path_to_chrome_driver -jar selenium_server.jar
```

Also make sure selenium server is compatible with chromedriver.
Other thing to check is that chrome browser is up to date.