# Can not Running Selenium with Eclipse with Java and BDD using Chrome or Firefox

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, selenium, firefox

I am trying to run Selenium but i am getting this error , any idea ? I am using selenium 3.0.0-beta2

Here is the Error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see 
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. 
The latest version can be downloaded from 
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
 at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
atorg.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:38)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:91)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:245)
 at 
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:220)
 at 
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:215)
 at 
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
 at 
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:124)
 at 
CCRX.CCRX2.App.user_at_login_p3age(App.java:36)
 at ✽.Given User at login page(src/test/resources/loginpage.feature:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mentioned, download the gecko driver from  https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases according to your requirements(Mine is windows). Unzip and locate the driver.

In your code add these,

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "Location of geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Also make sure you are using Firefox 48.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this once :

Write the code in Selenium under the main method:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
"path you downloaded/geckodriver.exe");// You have to set the Local path where you downloaded the driver.
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("www.google.com");
```

I think this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the driver first and after the selenium server.

For the selenium 3.0 the order of arguments changed, something like:

```
java -Dwebdriver... -jar selenium-server.jar
```

[the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdriver-chrome-driver-sys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834643/the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdriver-chrome-driver-sys)